# How do I list data stored in SQLite database as buttons?

Tags: android

I have information stored in a SQLite database and I want to attach images to each of them but they have to be of high quality so I understand that they can't be put it the database as well and I should connect them using a URL column; but how do I make the data from my database a click-able list so that the image opens when the list object is clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add column in table to store image path.
Insert image path to each row of table. this will not increase database size.

Modify model class of list object. eg. if you have `ArrayList<Students> studentList;` then Students class will be like this.

> Students.class

```
public class Students {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String imagePath;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

after modifying model class you have change your adapter as well.

Now in your listView.setOnItemClickListener you can get imagePath for each row in list. you can create new activity to show image on itemClick of listview. pass imagePath to another activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
//sending image path to next activity.
intent.putExtra("imagePath",arrayList.get(posistion).imagePath);
startIntent(intent);
```

Easiest way to show image is using Picasso library.

add this line in your app level gradle file

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String filePath = intent.getStringExtra("imagePath");
File file = new File("filePath");
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(file).into(imageView);
```